# reading file StringTokenizer to int

Tags: java, arrays, filereader, stringtokenizer

I have create the following program and I am little stuck here.
Here is the code:

```
class ProductNameQuan{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fileName = "stockhouse.txt";
        StringTokenizer line;
        String ProdName;
        String quantity;
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                 ProdName = line.nextToken();
                 quantity = line.nextToken();
                 System.out.println(line);
                 line = in.readLine();
            }
       in.close();
       } catch (IOException iox)
       {
           System.out.println("Problem reading " + fileName);
       }
    }
}
```

I am trying to find the way to read from the file the first 10 information's through the array (not arraylist)ProdName and the quantity." plus that I stack in the in.readLine(); propably is not compatible with the StringTokenizer.
Now the other problem is that I need the quantity to be an integer instead of string.

The file includes something like that:
Ball 32
tennis 322
fireball 54
..
.
.
.
.
Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason for using array instead of `ArrayList`?

Comment: The code that you posted is unnecessary. It'll be easier to all, to asume that you have read correctly the string.

Comment: You may parse the String like `int quantity =  Integer.parseInt(line.nextToken())`

Comment: I have to specify the array input lines that's why I need to be array instead of arraylist. Ecxept if I can do this through Arraylist

Comment: int quantity = Integer.parseInt(line.nextToken()) Where ecaxtly I have to put this? But still I put it in the quantity and still have problem with the in.readline

Comment: @user3079391 first change datatype of `quantity` to `int`
Then replace `quantity = line.nextToken()` to `Integer.parseInt(line.nextToken())`

Answer (score 0):

I would place this in a helper function, maybe called `parseString`

```
class ProductNameQuan {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ...
        try {
            BufferedReader in = ...
            line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                ProductNameQuan.parseString(line);
            }
        }
        ...
    }

    public static void parseString(String someString) 
    {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(someString);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = line.nextToken();
            try {
                int quantity = Integer.parseInt(token)
                // process number
            } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                // process string token
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for your quick reply, I am really impressed. Can you please help me where I have to put the above codes to my program? Really sorry and thanks too. :)

Comment: Right now I don't have a JDK available where I can iron out all the details, but that should give you the general idea.